# Access tokens expire after only 1 day

Tags: flattr

With my Flattr client using the REST API, it seems that access tokens expire after 1 day. I checked my settings and the client is still authenticated. But when I issue a request to `https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/user` I get the following response:

```
{ 
   "error":"unauthorized",
   "error_description":"You are unauthorized to access the resource",
   "error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"
}
```

Comment: That is strange, we don't expire tokens. If you try to request a new token with a different scope the old one will expire though. Please supply more information here or contact me for directly simon@flattr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I now know what the problem is. I am logging into Flattr with an iPhone and with the iPhone Simulator using the same account. It seems that using the API with more than one device will cause the user to need to login every time he changes devices.

I guess support for more than one access token at the same time is needed. Please confirm.

Comment: The bug is confirmed and should be patched now.